# Django Rest Framework : Unable to create a protected resource

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, tastypie, django-authentication

I am new to DRF and I want to create a protected resource which can be accessed only by using Token Auth header. The decorator `@authentication_classes` does not seem to work. When I send the GET request without auth token header - `$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/customers/2`,

I still get the response -

```
{"id":2,"person":{"id":2,"user":{"id":2,"mobile_number":"9999999999"},"first_name":"Yo","last_name":"Yolo","gender":"M"},"email":"b@b.com"}
```

What am I missing?

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views as rest_views
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^obtain-auth-token/', rest_views.obtain_auth_token),
    url(r'^customers/$', views.register_customer),
    url(r'^customers/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.customer_detail)
]
```

**views.py**

```
@api_view(["GET", "PUT"])
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
def customer_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == "GET":
        serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == "PUT":
        customer_serializer = CustomerSerializer(customer, data=request.data)
        person_serializer = PersonSerializer(customer.person, data=request.data)

        person_valid = person_serializer.is_valid()
        customer_valid = customer_serializer.is_valid()

        if person_valid and customer_valid:
            person_serializer.save()
            customer_serializer.save()
            return Response(request.data)
        else:
            errors = {}
            errors.update(person_serializer._errors)
            errors.update(customer_serializer._errors)

            return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Django REST Framework token authentication does only authentication, not the authorization. You need to set permissions as well. You can do it globally:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}
```

Or as a decorator:

```
@api_view(["GET", "PUT"])
@authentication_classes([authentication.TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def customer_detail(request, pk):
    pass
```